# Emptying the text field triggers the function, using the dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have the following on a page with one text input (name search) and one select (department filter). They work great, however there is one unique scenario where it's not playing nice.

If I do exactly this:

1. Selecting a department (ex: Accounting) shows all the people in the department
2. Entering a name in the text input (ex: Deb) narrows the department down to showing only people named Deb.
3. Pressing the delete/backspace key once (ex: De) expands the result to showing people with "De" in their name.
4. Pressing the delete/backspace key again (ex:D) expands the result further to show all with the letter D (or d) in their name.
5. Pressing it again makes all the results disappear!

It's frustrating. I want it to show ALL results of the Accounting department, since Name = "" and Department != "" ... please lend your thoughts.

```js
     <script>
     function showPEOPLE(str) {
       if (str=="") {
         document.getElementById("peopleResults").innerHTML="";
         return;
       } 
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
           document.getElementById("peopleResults").innerHTML=this.responseText;
         }
       }
      var d = document.forms["peopleSearchForm"]["peopleSearchDept"].value;
      var n = document.forms["peopleSearchForm"]["peopleSearchName"].value;
      if ((n == "") && (d != "")) {
       xmlhttp.open("GET","_resources/get_people_2.php?d="+d,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
      }
      if ((n != "") && (d == "")) {
       xmlhttp.open("GET","_resources/get_people_2.php?n="+n,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
      }
      if ((n != "") && (d != "")) {
       xmlhttp.open("GET","_resources/get_people_2.php?n="+n+"&d="+d,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
      }
     }
     </script>
```

Comment: What does your event handler function look like (the one that calls `showPeople()`)?

Comment: I have onchange="showPEOPLE(this.value)" as an attribute of the dropdown and onkeyup="showPEOPLE(this.value)" as an attribute of the text input.